# Jasperreports multiple subreports overlapping

Tags: java, pdf, jasper-reports, reporting, overlapping

I have a master detail with 2 subreports back to back `vertically` they don't have too much space because the master report is quite long.... I have specify in both subreports the `FLOAT` attribute. Everything works smoothly when the data of both fill in the space assigned in `IREPORT`, but when they have a lot of rows, I mean `3 or more rows`, the second subreport `Materiales` overlaps the next component... I would like if some subreport need more space it would push the next component down. The `TRABAJOS REALIZADOS` is into a `Frame with Float property` but is not pushed down the frame, it is maintaining the position and gets overlapped by `Materiales sub-report..`

my ireport design.

[image]

`my source code some tags are ommited by brevity`

```
<detail>
    <band height="770" splitType="Stretch">
        .... others tags ommited by brevity
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="401" width="554" height="70"/>
            <subreport runToBottom="false">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="1" width="553" height="69"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{munichs})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_EXPRESSION}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>                
        </frame>
        <frame>
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="2" y="472" width="551" height="128"/>
            <subreport runToBottom="false">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="1" y="44" width="545" height="83"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource($F{venices})]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[$P{SUBREPORT_EXPRESSION_SECOND_REPORT}]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
                     </frame>               
        <frame><!--this frame is not pushed down and gets overlapped...-->
            <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="599" width="554" height="171"/>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="2" y="1" width="180" height="20"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="1" width="178" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[TRABAJOS PENDIENTES]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <rectangle>
                <reportElement x="2" y="21" width="550" height="38"/>
            </rectangle>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="3" y="21" width="551" height="38"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$F{observations}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="2" y="64" width="100" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[FIRMA OPERADOR: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="333" y="64" width="107" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[CONFORME CLIENTE:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="442" y="63" width="22" height="22"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[$F{sign}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="188" y="90" width="66" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <text><![CDATA[FIRMA Y DNI:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="257" y="89" width="22" height="22"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[$F{conformity}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <image>
                <reportElement x="281" y="89" width="264" height="32"/>
                <imageExpression class="java.io.InputStream"><![CDATA[$F{imageForSign}]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="2" y="122" width="543" height="49"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression class="java.lang.String"><![CDATA[$P{lopd}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </frame>


    </band>
</detail>
```

my `IReport image`

[image]
***My PDF with overlapping..***

[image]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qByH1.png):

Comment: Your post isn't very clear.

Comment: Set property of subreport positionType as Float. It will solve your problem.

Comment: Please don't put "Solved" in the question title. Accept an answer instead. (You can accept your own answer, but only after 48 hours.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try by increasing height of detail band and if that doesn't work you can add one more detail, one for each sub-report.

To add detail band right click on "Detail" and add second band and copy second sub-report under this band.

Comment: i have try a bunch of workarounds and only your workarond worked for me thanks a lot... it worked adding a new `Detail Band` and put my stuff there..

Comment: but then report is showing in other page. I want to show 3 sub reports in one page. How to do it?. Can you help ?!!!

Comment: Just add detail bands for each subreport.

Comment: I find it best to put each sub report in a separate Detail band of the main report. That way, there is no issue of overlapping.

Answer (score 2):

Adjust the height one below the other sub report as you already set position type to float, It will work do the adjustment. 
If you make Group and place accordingly it will also work.

Comment: improve this so it can look like an answer instead of a comment

Comment: I have 4 year of experience in jasper Report with Php intigrating and Export.It's very difficult for me elaborate thing because there is always a multiple ways to do the single task. I will try to clear out my answer.